# Default Alacritty terminal for WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, wsl2, terminal-emulator

I just installed WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 on my Windows 10 machine and I also installed Alacritty terminal emulator for Windows. I'm wondering is there a way to make WSL to default into using Alacritty terminal over the default one? If so, any idea how to achieve it? Alacritty's github didn't say much about WSL (https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty).

Comment: What WSL do you mean? The start menu shortcuts? `wsl.exe`? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @DanielB Sorry I'm new to this... So pretty much I have a shortcut on the windows start menu that is named Ubuntu 20.04 and when I click it I want it to open up with the Alacritty terminal instead of the default terminal (that pops up atm when I click the Ubuntu shortcut). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, there's *currently* no way to change the default terminal that launches (WSL, PowerShell, CMD, etc.) to Alacritty.

Your best bet would be to create a small `.ps1` or `.cmd` script that would launch Alacritty with WSL.  You could then add that as a shortcut to the Start Menu for quick access.  Pinning it to the Start or Task bar would also be a possibility.

---

More background:

When this question was originally asked, it had just recently become possible to set Windows Terminal (Preview) in Windows 10 build 21390 (Insider/Preview).  You could select between the older Windows Console (which was the default) and the newer Windows Terminal.

Ultimately, the Insider builds of Windows 10 from that time became Windows 11.  Most new functionality was *not* rolled back to Windows 10 21H2, including this feature.

It *is* possible for other terminal applications to register themselves as replacement terminals as well, but it is not easy.  To quote from Alacritty issue [#6036](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/6036), which is tracking this feature request:

> If this takes what Christian Parpart described in the contour issue, I doubt this will ever be merged into Alacritty. But if there's some more minimal solutions, feel free to send a patch.

It requires creation and registration of a COM server for the terminal application, which might be a bit of a lost art (exaggeration, but it's definitely not something that is commonly done nowadays).

That said, Windows Terminal is open-sourced, so it's possible to examine exactly how it is implemented there.  The relevant code is, I believe in Windows Terminal [PR #7489](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/7489).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: Checking in, re: "soon", though I have to imagine the answer is "yes you can now"

Comment: @shmup Thanks for the ping.  Updated the answer.  Yes, it's now possible to set different terminals as the default in Windows 11, but they have to support it.  And it ain't easy.  To my knowledge there is no terminal other than Windows Terminal that has implemented the feature.

Answer (score 10):

modify your alacritty.yml shell section as below:

```yml
# Shell
#
# You can set `shell.program` to the path of your favorite shell, e.g.
# `/bin/fish`. Entries in `shell.args` are passed unmodified as arguments to the
# shell.
#
# Default:
#   - (macOS) /bin/bash --login
#   - (Linux/BSD) user login shell
#   - (Windows) powershell
shell:
  program: ubuntu
#  args:
#    - --login
```

Comment: this is correct answer

Comment: Actually you should find your wsl distro program in `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` and put the value here

Answer (score 4):

You can create a shortcut.

```
"C:\path\to\alacritty\alacritty.exe" --command ubuntu
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

At least for me the answer is to add following snippet to `alacritty.yml`

```yml
shell:
  program: wsl
```

Which is different from another answer where it says `ubuntu`for the program.

Comment: It does the exact same thing. Your answer launches the default WSL instance while the other launches a Ubuntu WSL provided it’s installed

Comment: The question is about how to get WSL to default to using Alacritty (instead of Windows Terminal or Windows Console Host), but your answer appears to be about how to get Alacritty to default to using WSL ;-).