# How to Make Windows Terminal the Default Shell on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-terminal

Previous builds of Windows Terminal allowed it to be defined the default shell for Windows 10 (See https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-terminal-can-now-be-the-default-windows-10-console/).

It seems this menu option was removed on Windows 10 from the current terminals.
Probably in order to leave as a special feature of Windows 11.

I wonder if there an hack to manually have the same effect.
Namely defined Windows Terminal as the default on Windows 10.

Comment: [I answered this question about Windows Terminal on Windows 10 back in 2020 and it’s still applicable.](https://superuser.com/questions/1557625/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-terminal-the-default-container-for-cmd-and-powers/1557629#1557629)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, for Windows 10 22H2 or later, you can set Windows Terminal as the default shell. If you are still using an older version of Windows 10, please consider upgrading to version 22H2, and then you can find the shell settings in Settings -- Upgrade&Security -- For Developers.

However, you may not able to run a shell with administrator privileges with Windows Terminal in Windows 10.  That is, if you run Cmd and Powershell with administrator privileges, Windows still only use the conhost.exe instead of wt.exe.

Answer (score 2):

*Original author's edit note:  My original answer below is now outdated.  Please see [@KenvixZure's answer](/a/1792816/1210833) for information on how to do this in the latest Windows 10 release. I'm leaving this answer here for historical purposes (and at the request of the question-poster).*

Sometimes "negative" answers ("no") are unfortunately the only answer.  While we can always hope that someone has a workaround, I don't believe that's likely to be the case.

> It seems this menu option was removed on Windows 10 from the current terminals. Probably in order to leave as a special feature of Windows 11.

Not really, no.  Those Windows changes in Windows 10 Insider weren't "removed".  Windows 10 Insider was the staging ground for what *became* Windows 11.  Based on that, it's completely expected that new features will only be available in Windows 11 going forward.  I don't expect Microsoft (or any developer) to backport new features to old releases.

And no, you can't run one of the old Windows 10 Insider builds, as they expire.

*Additional info:*

The feature was first made available in some Windows 10 Insider builds coupled, of course, with Windows Terminal preview builds.  There are two parts to the feature:

- The Windows/COM interface changes needed to allow a different terminal to be set as default.
- The implementation of a terminal that can implement the COM server necessary to act as the default.

In theory, it's possible to make changes to any terminal under Windows (ConEmu, Alacritty, etc.) to allow it to be set as default, but as I mention in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1658349/1210833), the COM implementation needed is quite difficult.

Comment: It seems they solved it.

Comment: Looks like - I'm going to test on one of my systems and delete my answer if so. Is it working for you?

Comment: It is working. Don't delete, it was correct at the time it was posted.